# Refreshing module/div on form submit [without page reload]

Tags: php, mysql

I have this simple search form inside a custom module.

**HTML FORM:**

```
<div id="search-form">
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="roll_no">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

// getting text from HTML text box

$roll_no = $_POST['roll_no'];

// executing MySql query to fetch a particular record

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('name')
       ->from($db->quoteName('students'))
       ->where($db->quoteName('student_id') . " = " . $db->quote($roll_no));

$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
$row = $db->loadrow();

echo $row['0'];

}
```

It works perfectly, but it refreshes the whole page. Can I somehow make it only refresh that particular module (div element).

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want, you can not submit the form.

You have to use an ajax call.

see jQuery.ajax documentation

Get a response and modify the DOM in order to reflect that response.

There is a nice example how to do it here:

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/search-ajax/

Comment: I have no experience with AJAX, can you explain it with some code?

Comment: I edited the answer to add a place with an example